# Rails 3: belongs_to, has_one and Migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Rails, and I'm coming to it from a Django background. I've come to terms with the fact that models and the database schema are separate in Rails, online Django. However, I'm still getting to grips with migrations.

My question is fairly simple - how do I add a relationship to a model using a migration? For example, I have `Artist` and `Song` as empty models that subclass `ActiveRecord::Base` at the moment, with no relationships whatsoever.

I need to move to doing this:

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :songs
end

class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
end
```

But how do I change the schema to reflect this using `rails g migrate`? I'm using Rails 3.1.3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add the foreign key in your migration file, something like this:

```
def change
  create_table :songs do |t|
    t.references :artist
  end

  add_index :songs, :artist_id
end
```

Comment: OK - and what if it's an existing table, do I need to use something other than `create_table`?

Comment: In that case you can use `add_column :songs, :artist_id, :int`, or if you want to make several changes on your table, `change_table`, with a syntax like the above. You can read more about migrations here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Comment: Thanks. I used `change_table`, but now when I go to "Songs" in ActiveAdmin, I get `no such column: artists.song_id`. Have I done something wrong? That column shouldn't exist, as an artist can have many songs...

Comment: Weird, if the association is the one that you posted, it should look for a the column `songs.artist_id`, not the other way around.

Comment: Hmm, I looked at `schema.rb` and can see the `artist_id` column in the `songs` table, but `artists` remains the same as it used to be - which is correct. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to access the association in a rails console, something like these `song = Song.first; song.artist = Artist.first; song.save!`, and if it doesn't give you any errors, then it should be some configuration with ActiveAdmin (for which I'm not familiar).

Answer (score 8):

You can generate migration

```
rails g migration AddProcedureIdToUser procedure:references
```

Thanks

Comment: should it be singular procedures?
`rails g migration AddProcedureIdToUser procedure:references`?

Comment: Your right @QuangVan, I updated my answer..  that should be singular

Comment: Your welcome @Anton, if you really helped this, plz give up vote for this ans

Comment: @prasanthrubyist I did

Comment: Thanks you @Anton

Answer (score 7):

Now, in Rails 4 you can do:

```
class AddProcedureIdToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :users, :procedure, index: true
  end
end
```

to an existing Model