# Does an ActiveRecord object that has_many children know when a child belongs_to it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an object model like:

```
class parent < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many: children
end

class child < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to: parent
end
```

My question is, if I do something like:

```
a_parent = Parent.create
child = Child.create(parent: a_parent)
```

Is there a clean way for the parent to be aware of the new child object so I can do something (like have the parent send out a birth announcement)? I'd rather not have the child do it (they can't even spell, let alone afford stamps). :)

I can imagine using an observer, or an after_create in the child to call a public method on the parent (calling parent.look_at_me). Ideally I'd like something that I define in the parent. Any other ideas?

Comment: The question you should ask yourself is 'does the parent need to know about the child?' I don't see why it would, unless some attributes of the parent change when it has a new child. If the birth announcement is a email message, I think you would just use an after_create or observer to message a Mailer class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Association callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Association+callbacks)

```
class Parent
  has_many :children, :after_add => :send_birth_announcement

  def send_birth_announcement(child)
    # ...
  end
end
```

This would work in cases like this:

```
a_parent.children << a_child
a_parent.children.create(child_attributes)
```

However, ORM is leaky abstraction, so it won't be hard to miss such callback. It's always possible to create a child without instantiating parent, so perhaps `after_create` in child isn't that bad of an idea.

Comment: Excellent tip. Thanks - I've been looking for that!

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer is yes, the parent knows about its children. This is done by having a `parent_id` field in the child table. Whenever a parent wants to find its children all it need do is ask that table for all children with the right parent id.

This is a fundamental concept of relational databases, well worth reading more about to make sure you understand what is happening when you use model associations.

Edit:
A slight code correction for your example

```
a_parent = Parent.create
child = Child.create(:parent => a_parent)
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to make sure you do the appropriate migration. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368580/rails-3-belongs-to-has-one-and-migrations).  Given you've done that, the code above  will automatically associate `a_parent` to its `child`.